# Navigation menu disappears until window is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Javascript to randomly load one image out of a series each time the window is opened or refreshed. The image represents a background image that takes up nearly half of the viewable window. Again, the image is random everytime.

The div for the image sits above a navigation bar, and for some reason when the image is loaded the li text within the navigation bar disappears (the actual nav bar stays) until the window is resized.

In my code the background image also is siting above the code for the navigation bar as they are positioned relative.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing what looks like a glitch? The issue is happening in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE11/10.

All you have to do is resize the window the slightest to make the nav ul li reappear, however, the navigation menu should not be hidden when the window is loaded, or should you have to resize the window to get the menu items to appear.

Any insight into what could be causing this issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/UavyG/1/

Thanks

```
Javascript and HTML Code below ----->
<!------------Random Image script   start  below------------>
<div id="main-image">
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = ['type-writer.jpg', 'quechua3.jpg', 'chicago3.jpg', 'type-writer-books.jpg', 'one-hundred-plus-forty-eight.jpg'];
$('#main-image').css({'background-image': 'url(images/cover-images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
$('<img src="images/cover-images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('#main-image');
</script>
</div>
<!------------Random Image script   END------------>



<nav class="container">
<div id="mobile-logo"><img src="images/logo-2.svg" width="70px" alt="3Elements Review, a literary journal based in Chicago, Illinois. This is our magazine's logo." border="none" id="mobile-logo"></div>
<ul>
<li class="current" style="background-color:#313131;"><a href="current-journal.html" class="current">CURRENT JOURNAL<span class="sub-nav">Our latest and greatest!</span></a></li>
<li class="submit" style="background-color:#404040;"><a href="submit.html" class="current">SUBMIT<span class="sub-nav">Your writing</span></a></li>
<li class="guidelines" style="background-color:#505050;"><a href="submission-guidelines.html" class="current">SUBMISSION GUIDELINES<span class="sub-nav">Everything you need to know is here</span></a></li>
<li class="blog" style="background-color:#4b4b4b;"><a href="3eblog.html" class="current">BLOG<span class="sub-nav">Just a blog</span></a></li>
<li class="past" style="background-color:#404040;"><a href="past-journals.html" class="current">PAST JOURNALS<span class="sub-nav">Browse our issue archives</span></a></li>
<li class="about" style="background-color:#313131;"><a href="about-3elements.html" class="current">ABOUT 3E<span class="sub-nav">What we're about</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

-----------CSS------------

```
    nav.container {
    position:relative;
    top:-5px!important;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#252525;
    z-index:50;
    border-bottom:5px solid #ffd09d;
}

nav.container ul {
    position:relative;
    height:70px;
    top:-63px;
    margin:0px!important;
    padding:0px!important;
    text-align:center;
}

nav.container ul li a:hover > span {
    color:#ffffff!important;
}

.current, .submit, .guidelines, .blog, .past, .about {
    position:relative;
    margin-right:-4px;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-right:13px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:1.5px;
    top:1px;
    left:0px;
    font-family:myriad pro, arial, sans-serif;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:1.46em;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:1.95em;
    outline:none;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    transition:750ms;
    -webkit-transition:750ms;
    list-style:none;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#252525;
}

li.current:hover, li.submit:hover, li.guidelines:hover, li.blog:hover, li.past:hover, li.about:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#beb29a!important;
    border-bottom:15px solid #ff6000!important;
    transition:100ms;
    -webkit-transition:100ms;
}
#main-image img {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code I had another script that controls the toggling/slidedown of a menu item. This menu, as well as the main navigation menu both use the nav property.

In my javascript code I just had to further target my css instead of using nav ul, as not being more precise in the javascript code for my mobile menu, affected my main navigation menu, causing it to be hidden briefly until the window was resized.

So I changed one line of code like so:

```
<script>
$(function () {
        var pull = $('button.open-menu');
        menu = $('ul.nav-menu');
        menuHeight = menu.height();
        menu.slideToggle(0);
        $(pull).on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function () {
            var w = $(window).width();
            if (w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

from this: menu = $('nav ul');

to this: menu = $('ul.nav-menu');